# ChunkyPNG ruby gem alternatives

Tags: ruby

I am trying to write a small image processing ruby program, and I am using ChunkyPNG to load and write to pixels. The problem with ChunkyPNG is that it's loading time is so slow. It takes  quite a while to load a 1mb~3mb png file. Any alternatives ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OilyPNG maybe?  https://github.com/wvanbergen/oily_png

From the README:

OilyPNG is a Ruby C extension to speed up the pure Ruby ChunkyPNG library. It is a standalone module, so it does not require LibPNG, ImageMagick or any other library. Currently it has an alternative implementation of decoding and encoding PNGs, making these operations much faster, especially for PNG images that apply filtering.

Comment: will it allow me to edit pixels?

Comment: @Test Test: Yes. It is a library for speeding up ChunkyPNG, you `require “oily_png”` then use ChunkyPNG api as normal, and some of the operations automagically become faster.

Comment: why will he keep it separate then ?

Comment: Because not all of us need the speed or want the C extension.